# Reverse GeoCode in Asia

Tags: flutter, here-api, reverse-geocoding

in my flutter app I use the package here_maps_webservice (v1.0.3) for reverse-geocoding. It works very well for european addresses. But for latitudes and longitudes in China, I get just the country name: People's republic of China.
Is it not yet possible to get more details for positions in China/Asia?

Xinyu

Answer (score 0):

Mobile SDK including Flutter SDK does not support for China(main land).

Please see below coverage information.

Coverage Information
https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.8.0.0/dev_guide/topics/coverage-information.html

Places and Search / Geocoding / Reverse Geocoding
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/search-local-coverage.html